# Is it possible to exclude other css style affect on specified dom element

Tags: css

I got a project from one of my friend,

The project has hundreds of css files.

and now I need to a notify plugin, http://sciactive.github.io/pnotify/

but I found the plugin's css will be affected by other css files.

Is it possible to only apply **pnotify.css**  on the following DOM ,

And prevent other css files affect on it ?

Or is there any idea to workaround the problem

```
<div class="ui-pnotify stack-bottomright" style="width: 300px; opacity: 1; display: block; overflow: visible; right: 25px; top: 0px; cursor: auto;"><div class="alert ui-pnotify-container  ui-pnotify-shadow" style="min-height: 16px; overflow: hidden;"><div class="ui-pnotify-closer" style="cursor: pointer; visibility: hidden;"><span class="icon-remove" title="Close"></span></div><div class="ui-pnotify-sticker" style="cursor: pointer; visibility: hidden;"><span class="icon-play" title="Stick"></span></div><div class="ui-pnotify-icon"><span class="icon-exclamation-sign"></span></div><h4 class="ui-pnotify-title">獎項更新</h4><div class="ui-pnotify-text" style="display: none;"></div><div style="margin-top: 5px; clear: both; text-align: right; display: none;"></div></div></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably have to reset the style for the certain div (which is obviously not working if I understand you right) or add the !important statement to the css-file/classes you want to use. But you can't be 100% sure that this one is used if there are multiple !importants in the different css files. Depends on the files and their structure.

Comment: is it possible to make `!important` for whole css file ?  it's hard to and the !important line by line, thanks

Comment: Sadly you can't. !important is set per property. But macros like in Notpad++ could help you to modify the CSS.